# Real Time - Event Tracking with Google Analytics API?

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I searched around this site to try to find a similar answer, but I had no luck.

What I'm trying to do is set up an image, ad, or button and tag in it with event listeners, so that I can track events.  I've managed to do this, but what I really need is something that will let me gather the interaction data of each individual, provide a unique id for each individual, and gather real-time event interaction information, so that I can record and possibly act on different events based on user interaction.

I was looking into google analytics for this because I can see the real-time events, but I don't know if it is possible to call these events in the way I explained.  Ideally there would be an api call I could make with a populated unique id to pull in the event interaction information in real time.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to put client id into a custom variable/dimension and you could then segment based on a unique id, not in real-time however. I was then going to say, have you looked at [Google Analytics Real-time reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/), but then I was looking at the [Dimensions & Metics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/) and noticed that you can't pull in custom dimensions nor events.

Does it have to be real-time? The reason I ask is that it's possible to do this using the Core Reporting API, or the UI itself.

Comment: Thanks! - I was thinking about this too.  I suppose it doesn't have to be real time (though that would be ideal), but the most important elements are the unique identifier and event tracking.